# WAMP not working on Windows 7 Enterprise

Tags: windows, wamp

I am using WAMP on Windows 7 Enterprise. It was working fine initially, even though the icon remained red in the tray. My PC remains on 24x7 but yesterday I restarted it due to a pending windows update. And now, WAMP no longer works i.e. I cannot access anything under localhost. The browser (chrome) returns a webpage unavailable error.

I do not have Skype installed. I did try and test, and it said that Port 80 is used by some other application. As I do not have admin rights, I reconfigured the httpd.conf file for Apache to port 81, but even that did not help.

I also ran a netstat -ao using CMD, but I could not find anything running on Port 80.

Any ideas as to what can be done to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: may be wamp process is now blocked by the windows 7 because of the update. You should have a look at the service that are pending / waiting for action / required an authorization etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my windows 7 home basic.

Maybe you could solve by this:

1)Your port 80 is mostly blocked by Microsoft iis server. so if iis is using port 80 than apache wont be able to use the port.

2) So, change the listening port of apache. apache has a file name httpd.conf.Open the file in a text editor and there will be port 80 already written,  change the port to 8080 (mostly people use 8080).

3)So now your Apache runs on different port.

4) Restart apache services or restart your wamp server.

5)now Open your local host by, localhost:8080

6)you will see your localhost page.

Hope it solved your problem.